# Jersey - Declarative Hyperlinking - In Code Configuration

Tags: java, jersey, hateoas

Hi I'm going through the Jersey Getting Started Guide.

In [Chapter 6](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/linking.html) they use the @Ref annotation to inject the URI of a resource.  I've followed the example, but my uri is always null.

How can I add the `com.sun.jersey.server.linking.LinkFilter` to `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters` programatically?  I've already seen a bunch of examples using web.xml.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up retrieving the `ResponseFilters` from the `ResourceConfig` and then adding an instance of `LinkFilter` to it.

```
private static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
        LOG.info("Starting server...");
        ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.mycomp.resources");
        rc.getContainerResponseFilters().add(new com.sun.jersey.server.linking.LinkFilter());
        return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
    }
```